# SetSelectedItem doesnt jump to selected item after clicking the box

Tags: java, combobox, selecteditem

I have a combobox which I fill and pick the needed item with selectedItem but not with selectedIndex.

In case of selectedIndex it sets the needed value in the combobox, and highlights the selection. but in case of selectedItem it selects what I need, but when i press the box it shows list from the very begining.

how to set the selected item without using the setSelectedIndex ?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if u had posted code here. but yet.. Please read below text from javaDocs about setSelectedItem:

```
 Sets the selected item in the combo box display area to the object in the argument. If anObject is in the list, the display area shows anObject selected.
    If anObject is not in the list and the combo box is uneditable, it will not change the current selection. For editable combo boxes, the selection will change to anObject. 

    If this constitutes a change in the selected item, ItemListeners added to the combo box will be notified with one or two ItemEvents. If there is a current selected item, an ItemEvent will be fired and the state change will be ItemEvent.DESELECTED.If anObject is in the list and is not currently selected then an ItemEvent will be fired and the state change will be ItemEvent.SELECTED.
```